# Build shiboken for Python 2.7x64 on Windows 7

Tags: python, qt, windows-7, 64-bit, pyside

Has anyone done a successful build of shiboken for Python 2.7x64 on Windows 7.  I've tried to follow tons of different instructions online and haven't been able to get it to build.  I will happily PayPal someone if they have a build that they can just send me or some followable instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instructions on how to compile PySide, including Shiboken are [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide#building-pyside-on-a-windows-system)

Also the shiboken binaries are included in every windows distribution. Just install the pyside python egg via easy_install and search for shiboken.exe in site packages.

EDIT:

Shiboken is now [available on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shiboken) as standalone package.
You can install shiboken binaries via pip or easy_install.

Comment: You can just copy:  C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PySide\shiboken*  to:  C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\  then "import shiboken"  works fine!  Who would have guessed? Why don't they just put it in the site-packages by default!  I tried to compile it like all morning!

Comment: There will be a separate Shiboken distribution in near future, so to install Shiboken you don't need the entire PySide.